# How can I align the border at the center of the html page

Tags: html, center

```
<html> 
<body>
<div align="center" style="width=1000;height=100;padding=10;border=10  solid dark-blue ;"> <h> <B> hello </B> </h> <BR></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my html code. Can anyone help me with putting this border in the middle of the page without using CSS?

Comment: <div align="center" style="width:1000px;height:100px;padding:10px;border:10px solid darkblue ;">
<h1>  <B> BLABLABLA</B> </h1> <br>
</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enclose the "**div**" in  tag. That will do the trick!

```
<html>
</body>
<center>
<div align="center" style="width:1000px;height:100px;padding:10px;border:10px solid darkblue ;"> <h1> <B> BLABLABLA</B> </h1> <br> </div>
</center></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Really, [`center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) in 2016?

Comment: The things that are needed to be used, can be used at any instance of time. In this case center did the trick.